# How to share an image from a iOS Safari Web page using native share API?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

I would like to share an image from a HTML5 page using Navigator Share API like:

```
navigator.share({ files: [myImageFile], title: "My Title" });
```

It works very well on Andoid Chrome But I'be facing issues with iOS Mobile Safari. On iOS Safari only the "title" is shared.

How can I invoke the native iOS share dialog and share an image from a web page?

- PS1. It doesn't necessarily must use `navigator.share`api
- PS2. My main target is WhatsApp, Any whatsapp specific solution would be nice too.

Comment: Safari must support the web share level 2 api, which it doesn't yet.